# How to do rapid Sharepoint Ribbon development?

Tags: ribbon

What is the most effective way of developing SharePoint Ribbon funtionality today? I've tried Add-In Express' SharePoint Ribbon Designer, but they only support Visual Studio 2013 and below. (https://www.add-in-express.com/office365-sharepoint-ribbon-designer/index.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful, check out github SharePoint/pnp:

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.RibbonCommands

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/add-a-custom-ribbon-to-your-sharepoint-site

http://aaclage.blogspot.co.za/2014/04/examples-of-customization-of-ribbons-in.html